# Line Chart Labels - Ng2Charts - ChartJS

Tags: chart.js, ng2-charts

trying to make a line chart with multiple lines. One problem I am running with is that, my dataset looks something like

```
[{
    data: [12,3,4,5] , label: Line A
},
    data: [3,2,1], label: Line B
]
```

Thing is when I push these data points into the set they are associated with a time. Something like below. The order these times are pushed is the order that it is pushed into the dataset. So Ex) Dataset with Label Line A was pushed in 
with the first 4 labels. Label Line B pushed in the last 3 time labels.
Now when the graph is created, Line B is misleading because and it is being positioned with the first 3 label. 
  public lineChartLabels:Array = ['10:10', '10:20', '10:30', '11:50', '11:51', '11:52', '11:53'];

Reading the documentation , need to specific points as so.

```
data: [{
        x: 10,
        y: 20
    }, {
        x: 15,
        y: 10
    }]
```

Tried this and the lines would not render. If anyone is able to provide a example that would be greatly appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to make the chart type 'time'

```
public lineChartOptions: any = {
  responsive: true,
  scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    type: 'time',
    distribution: 'linear'
  }]
 }
};
```